# How to iterate objects from JSON array file in batch script

Tags: json, batch-file, curl

I have a windows batch script to perform POST request using curl and reads the data from JSON file, it works fine with only a single object in the file and it looks like this.

```
curl -u username@password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @file.json http://apiurl.com
```

and the json file is this:

```
{
  "name": "Empty name",
  "properties": {
    "active": "True",
    "subcity_zone": "East Hararge",
    "woreda": "Meta"
   }
}
```

But now I want to send the request each object in the array by iterating each item. So, How do I iterate each JSON object from the file?

Here is what the new JSON array file looks like:

```
[{
    "name": "test facility I",
    "properties": {
        "active": "True",
        "city": "",
        "subcity_zone": "East Hararge",
        "woreda": "Meta"
    }
},
{
    "name": "test facility II",
    "properties": {
        "active": "True",
        "subcity_zone": "East Hararge",
        "woreda": "Girawa"
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
jq -c '.[]' file | while read js; do 
  curl -u username@password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @<(echo "$js") http://apiurl.com
done
```

The `jq` command extracts the each object in one line that is read by `read` command into the `$js` variable.

The `<(echo "$js")` creates a temporary file that is passed to `curl`.